# Accessing packed field in Rust and Compiler recommendation

Tags: rust, memory-safety

Consider following simple rust program

```rust
#[repr(packed)]
pub struct TwuMsg {
    pub id: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let msg = TwuMsg { id: 1 };
    println!("msg.id {}", msg.id);
}
```

It fails to compile. rustc suggests following help

```
= help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)
```

But if I change `main` according to note, It works fine.

```rust
fn main() {
    let msg = TwuMsg { id: 1 };
    // isn't msg.id is also accessing unaligned field too? Why it's considered safe?
    let id = msg.id;
    println!("msg.id {}", id);
}
```

I tried to get answers from different sources. They claimed that rust compiler ensures the safety. Then my counter would be

> why rustc can't ensure safety for direct reference to field if it can for copy operation?

If you can explain the diff in terms of CPU and instructions generated that would be deeply appreciated.

### [UPDATE]

I've gone through official reference already at https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#places-based-on-misaligned-pointers but I'm more interested to know about the motive behind this design decision.
Usually if data is unaligned CPU will spend additional cycle for the read.
Is performance penalty is the only reason behind considering this a *UB*?

Comment: I'd suppose it's considered safe since the assignment transposes the value into the correct alignment when creating the `id` copy.

Answer (score 2):

Rust has the invariant that references are always aligned to the type's required alignment. Violating this invariant is Undefined Behavior.

Packed structs have unaligned fields, so you cannot take reference to them, only raw pointers or copy or direct assignment. `println!()` implicitly takes references to its arguments, so it cannot be used with packed fields.

Note that you don't need an additional variable; using curly braces will force a copy:

```rust
println!("msg.id {}", { msg.id });
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7f0a7a612b82000d0af6a27f4f18dce).

Also note that debating about CPU support for unaligned access is **not** correct here. Even if the CPU does not support unaligned store or load, Rust will still make them work (for example, by copying bytes). References could be made to work in the same way. The only reason is that unaligned references are UB. *Why* this is the case can be attributed (at least partially) to micro-architectures penalizing unaligned access.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the memory allocation for rust's secure access system. First when you use `#[repr(packed)]` `rust` will sort the fields with minimal alignment leading to some fields that can never be aligned (this is due to the way memory is allocated Rust hardware does not determine it). unaligned access and field leads to uncomputable behavior (it's easy to hack like ios m8 bug)

in the first code you try to directly access `msg.id` of type `u64 8byte` from an address that may not be `8 byte` this is dangerous behavior `rustc` will ban it

In the second code you are doing a read of `let id = msg.id` you are copying to `id` which is safe because it will copy the bytes from `msg.id` to `id` without caring about the alignment of the result is `id` aligned to `8 bytes` because rust always ensures correct local variable alignment

important here rust ensures compile safe copying as it involves moving bytes but it cannot guarantee safe reference to fields as it involves unsafe memory access

Easy explanation `[repr(packed)]` rust will not provide any `padding` . for example if `id` only has `6 bytes` then rust will give it a whole row of `bytes` because there is nothing `2 bytes` to put in that place so `id` can instead be accessed Its `6 bytes' have the ability to access another` 2 bytes' next to it in the memory bar. If you don't want to use `let id = msg.id` you can `#[repr(C)]` this mode will add padding to fill the memory to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: @cafce25 I want to use it to highlight. We don't have to follow the rules. I'm pretty sure that most people never pay attention to the meaning of html tags

Comment: Maybe not, but misusing semantic tags makes html documents strictly worse (even if only by a little), [so] answers like yours aren't exempt from that. And there are tools other than plain browsers which make semantic tags behave in a different way than you see (screen readers for example) which will make that tag very confusing to users of them.